# New Facebook approval process , how to test ios app

Tags: facebook

Long time I haven't developed with Facebook API , and now I have iOS app that using graph api to upload   image and status to Facebook all working fine . But the problem is that I can't really test it with real users .
It seams like the app is in some kind of testing mode until get approved .
Question is how can I get approved Before I upload the app to AppStore?

Answer (score 0):

Go To facebook profile click on manage app and then from MYApp section on top choose You app and then from left click status&review and then on the right hand side you will see a button name Start a Submission click on that button.